# Catch All Queries with a Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a rather long Sql query that needs different where clauses depending on user choices.

I have done some searching, and [this](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) seems to be the most comprehensive article on the matter.

However, it doesn't mention the option of using the table valued function to achieve the same effect, and to me, this seems to be the most optimum answer.

Am I missing something?

Here is my catch all query written with the TVF:

```
--These paramenters will always be passed
declare @tenantId int = 7;
declare @yesterday DateTime = dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETUTCDATE()),0);
declare @tomorrow DateTime = dateadd(day,datediff(day,-1,GETUTCDATE()),0);

--These are optional:
declare @parentId int = 230;  --In this example, @parentId is populated.
declare @ownedById int = null; --In this example, @ownedBy is not populated.


--Simple if statement:
if @parentId is not null
    BEGIN
        if @ownedById is not null
            BEGIN
            Select * from GetItemInfos(@tenantId, @yesterday, @tomorrow)
                where ParentId = @parentId and OwnedById = @ownedById;
            END
        ELSE
            Select * from GetItemInfos(@tenantId, @yesterday, @tomorrow)
                where ParentId = @parentId;
    END
ELSE IF @ownedById is not null
    BEGIN
        Select * from GetItemInfos(@tenantId, @yesterday, @tomorrow)
                where OwnedById = @ownedById;
    END
ELSE
    Select * from GetItemInfos(@tenantId, @yesterday, @tomorrow);
```

And here is the TVF:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION GetItemInfos 
(   
    @tenantId int,
    @yesterday DateTime,
    @tomorrow DateTime

)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

Select i.Id,
    i.AssignedToId,
    i.ParentId,
    i.OwnedById,
    i.Budget,
    i.CloseDate,
    i.CloseStatusId,

    AssignedToName = Concat(anu.FirstName, ' ', anu.LastName),
    OwnedByName = Concat(anu2.FirstName, ' ', anu2.LastName),
    CloseStatusName = cs.Name,

    i.ItemTypeId,

    ItemTypeIcon = it.Icon,

    i.ImportanceTypeId,
    ImportanceTypeDescription = ImportanceTypes.Description,

    i.EntityStatusId,
    i.DueDate,
    IsOverdue = 
        case when i.CloseStatusId = 1 and i.DueDate <= @yesterday then Cast(1 as bit)
        else Cast(0 as bit)
        end,
    IsDue =
        case when i.CloseStatusId = 1 and i.DueDate >= @yesterday and i.DueDate < @tomorrow then cast(1 as bit)
        else Cast(0 as bit)
        end,
    IsClosed = case when (i.CloseStatusId != 1) then cast(1 as bit) else cast(0 as bit) end,
    i.Cost,
    ItemTypeShowProperties = it.ShowProperties,
    ItemTypeSortOrder = it.SortOrder,
    PriorityTypeDescription =  PriorityTypes.Description,
    PriorityTypeSortOrder = PriorityTypes.SortOrder,
    i.Name,
    i.PriorityTypeId,
    Progress = Convert(nvarchar, i.Progress) + '%',
    i.SortOrder,
    i.StartDate,
    StatusTypeName = StatusTypes.Name,
    i.TimeEstimate,
    TimeScaleTypeName = TimeScaleTypes.Name 

 from Items i 

 left join AppUsers au
 on i.AssignedToId = au.Id
    left join AspNetUsers anu
    on au.AspNetUserId = anu.id

 left join AppUsers au2
 on i.OwnedById = au2.Id
    left join AspNetUsers anu2
    on au2.AspNetUserId = anu2.id

 left join CloseStatuses cs
 on i.CloseStatusId = cs.id

 left join ItemTypes it
 on i.ItemTypeId = it.Id

 left join ImportanceTypes 
 on i.ImportanceTypeId = ImportanceTypes.Id

 left join PriorityTypes 
 on i.PriorityTypeId = PriorityTypes.Id

 left join StatusTypes
 on i.StatusTypeId = StatusTypes.Id

 left join TimeScaleTypes
 on i.TimeScaleTypeId = TimeScaleTypes.Id

 where  i.TenantId = @tenantid 

)
GO
```

**EDIT**
Based on the comments, this seems to be the best way to write this:

```
Select * from GetItemInfos(@tenantId, @yesterday, @tomorrow)
    where (@parentId is null or ParentId = @parentId) and (@ownedById is null or OwnedById = @ownedById) OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: What problem of catch-all queries does the table valued function solve?

Comment: The problem is not wanting to write the base sql statement twice.  (DRY - Don't repeat yourself)

Comment: But that is not the problem with catch-all queries... the problem is that the cached execution plan might not be the best execution plan for a different set of parameters. You can create catch-all queries without repeating yourself simply by manipulating the where clause like this: `where (@x is null or @x = x) and (@y is null or @y = y)...` So you write only a single query with no if...else and no need for another function.

Comment: BTW, you might also want to read what SQL Server MVP Erland Sommarskog has to say about it in his article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL.](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Ok, so how about this form which hides the complexity of the base Sql Statement (also allowing it to be used elsewhere): `Select * from GetItemInfos(@tenantId, @yesterday, @tomorrow)
 where (@parentId is null or ParentId = @parentId) and (@ownedById is null or OwnedById = @ownedById) ;`

Comment: This still doesn't solve the main problem with the catch-all queries. That's why we use the `recompile` hint or dynamic SQL to begin with...

Comment: You'll most lilely want to add the `RECOMPILE` option to that.

Comment: Good point, see edited question.